# Android AutoCompleteTextView from ArrayList not showing

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am trying to set an AutoCompleteTextView field edtNumeAsig and after 3 characters are written down in it I am trying to update the autocomplete.

Unfortunatelly from this demo I couldn't make it work, auto complete isn't displaying.

```
ArrayList<String> ASIGURATORI = new ArrayList<String>();

ASIGURATORI.add("BAFF");
ASIGURATORI.add("fsfsg");
ASIGURATORI.add("BAFFFEFEFF");
ASIGURATORI.add("444");

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AgentRegisterActivity.this
                    , android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, ASIGURATORI);
edtNumeAsig.setAdapter(adapter);
edtNumeAsig.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            Toast.makeText(AgentRegisterActivity.this, s.length() +"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if(s.length() >=3) {
                ASIGURATORI.add("YOLO");
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
    });
```

Comment: You don't need to add textchangedlistener for dropdrown auto complete list to pop up. When you set your adapter for autocompletetextview, you dont need anything more if you are ok with default customization.

Comment: on text >= 3 characters I will get the ArrayList<String> ASIGURATORI from an web service, so I need it..

Comment: can you try edtNumeAsig.setThreshold(1); lets see anything pops up. type  B or 4 on runtime

Comment: now it works :D thanks. can you post it as an answer to award you?

Comment: your welcome anytime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use setThreshold(1) for it